# How to only show the note of the math underbrace, and hide underbrace bracket?

Tags: math-mode, amsmath, braces, annotations, underbrace

How can I hide the underbrace curly bracket and only show the overhead note `(note here)` (and not `n times` shown underneath)? Better yet, is there a TeX command that only does the note, i.e. an overhead note command?

`\underbrace{x + \cdots + x}_{n\rm\ times}^{\text{(note here)}}`

[image]

Comment: You can do it with ```\underset``` and ```\overset```


```$\underset{n\text{ times}}{\overset{(\text{note here})}{x+\cdots+x}}$```

Comment: You can use `\overset{\text{(note here)}}{x+\dots+x}` (requires `amsmath`).